# Reputation requirements have not been changed

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

As much as I may enjoy the fact I can still inline retag posts and access the 10k tools, I must report the rep requirements haven't changed yet from the public beta.

Are we sticking with close at 500, edit at 1000 and tools at 2000 for the foreseeable future or is it simply an overlook from the team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was fixed, and there is even the nifty (new?) [privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/) page.